# Why updating firebase-realtime-db goes into an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this simple code which I try to update my firebase realtime db.

When I use `update()` the code goes into an infinite loop in the line: `return update(listsRef, updates)`:

```
  const HandleEditFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    //Updated contact information
    const updatedContact = {
      id: editContactId,
      fullName: editFormData.fullName
    }

    //Updating Firebase RT-DB
    onValue(listsRef, (snapshot) => {
      const jsonObject = snapshot.val()
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(jsonObject)) {
        if (value['id'] === editContactId) {
          const updates = {}
          updates[key] = updatedContact
          return update(listsRef, updates)
          //TODO: WHY DO I HAVE AN INFINITE LOOP HERE?!
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

And the error looks like this:

[image]

Until everything crashes:

[image]

But when I change the code to this one using `get()` everything works well:

```
  const HandleEditFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    //Updated contact information
    const updatedContact = {
      id: editContactId,
      fullName: editFormData.fullName
    }

    //Updating Firebase RT-DB
    get(listsRef).then(snapshot => {
      if(snapshot.exists()){
        const jsonObject = snapshot.val()
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(jsonObject)) {
          if (value['id'] === editContactId) {
            const updates = {}
            updates[key] = updatedContact
            return update(listsRef, updates)
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

I already read the [Firebase Docs (Modular SDK v9)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web-version-9_5) but I didn't find why `update()` goes into an infinite loop and `update()` after `get()` works just fine & I don't have a clue why my code works now.

I'm just a beginner with Firebase & React, I'll appreciate any help to understand better why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onValue trigger when changes happen on specific location **listsRef**
[reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database#onvalue_3).

the issue here that you are updating the same location **listsRef** that made **onValue()** run again